# How to use jQuery Validation plugin with form-level server-side validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

What's the best way to trigger errors on elements for server-side validation errors that come back after the form passes the initial client-side validation?

```
$("#contact_form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/contact/send',
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        if(response.error) { //server came back with validation issues
          var fields = response.fields;
          for(var i=0, var len = fields.length; i < len; i++) {
            var field_name = fields[i].name;
            var field_error = fields[i].error;

            // TRIGGER ERROR ON AFFECTED ELEMENT

          }
          return false;
        }
        //everything went ok, so let's show a thanks message
        showThanks();
      }
    }
});
```

I'm thinking something like:

```
$(form).find("[name='" + field_name + "']").triggerError(field_error);
```

But I didn't see any api methods for manually triggering errors in that manner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I figured it out from the documentation of [Validator/showErrors](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors#errors)

```
var validator = $("#contact_form").validate();
validator.showErrors({"state": "Bad state."});
```

Comment: How to show multiple error messages on single field. Like {'state': ['bad state', 'should be 5 charactors']}

Answer (score 0):

Make it. [Write a plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Plug_me%3a_Writing_your_own_plugins) that will do whatever you want.
Or if you get to complicated, simply write a javascript function to do it and call that.

I would write a plugin that would create a div, fill it with the error text and animate it nicely.

Comment: I actually started rolling my own plugin but I wanted to try and avoid re-inventing wheels if I could.  This is really the only functionality I'm missing and it seems like a fairly common use case, so I'm just trying to see if anyone else has run into it before I spend the time to roll my own.

Comment: I generally sense that the best job is the one you do yourself. I quick search offered no results, maybe someone who knows a plugin like that specifically, for now, I'd write a very simple plugin

Answer (score -3):

On submit of the form, I would make the target of the form an invisible iframe on the page which would then call a function in the topWindow with it's result.

```
<iframe id="subject_frame" name="submit_frame" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

then in the page in the iframe call a javascript method in the top window that either redirects on success or displays the errors.

**In the iframe**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   window.top.window.submitComplete("<?php echo $response; ?>");
</script>
```

**In the top window** (as an example)

```
function uploadComplete( result ){
    $.unblockUI();
    if(result == "OK"){
        $.blockUI({ message: "<span style='color:green;'>File upload successful, request submitted.</span><br/><br/>Redirecting..." }); 
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $.unblockUI({ 
                onUnblock: function(){ window.location='thankyou.php'; } 
            }); 
        }, 2000);

    } else {
        $.blockUI({ message: "<span style='color:red;'>Failed.</span><br/><br/>"+result }); 
        $('.blockOverlay').attr('title','Click to remove').click($.unblockUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using an `iFrame` is far from ideal in this case. There are much better technologies to use in this case.

Comment: I've already got the form submission process under control, I just want to be able to trigger errors just like they were any other client-side validation error based on the response.