# jQuery Validate won't clear server-inserted error messages on KeyUp

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

We are using the JQuery Validate plugin to do simple field validation. Everything works as expected when using default, client-side validation.

However, some of these fields require server-side validation. The problem occurs when manually creating error labels on the server in the HTML.  When doing so, the error label displays as expected, however the behavior is wrong.

Essentially, once the error label is displayed, it won't be removed on the KeyUp event of the field. It will only be removed when you press the submit button, and this first press of the submit button only hides the error label and sets the input field to valid. You have to press the submit button a second time to actually have the form submit. It appears JQuery validate knows about the error label and it's connected input field, else it wouldn't be hidden when pressing the submit button.

Things I've tried:

- setting `generated="true"` on the error label (no change)
- removing the server-side label generation and returning an error code which then creates the label on the client side with the Validator object, yet the behavior is the same (have to press the submit button first to remove the label and a second time to submit the form):

  ```
  var validator = $( "#form ).validate();
  validator.showErrors({
  "password": "invalid password"
  });
  ```

Here is an example form with server returned error label (using Thymeleaf):

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="ex-label" th:text="#    {common.password}">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control ex-input-modal required" /> 
    <label th:if="${passFail}" for="password" class="error"> Wrong password     </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect.  jQuery Validate is a ***client-side*** script, so you can't expect it to have anything to do anything with server generated messages.  The plugin automatically generates and then toggles its own error message labels.  The idea is that, when the plugin is installed, the user would never see the server-side validation.  The server-side validation would only be there to protect you in case JavaScript is disabled or bypassed.

Comment: Since you cannot submit the form to the server until jQuery Validate is satisfied, how could you ever see any server generated validation messages in the first place?

Comment: it DOES recognize the server generated labels in some way, since it will clear them on the OnBlur or form submit events. Similarly, If I programmatically call Validate() on the field, the label will be removed.

Comment: As far as not being able to ever see the server validation messages, the server-side labels are returned in the html on page load AFTER the client-side validation is satisfied and the form is submitted (ex: an email address field is properly formatted, so the form is allowed to be submitted. However, it is determined on the server that the email address already exists, and the server returns an error label)

Comment: Regardless, the client side plugin is not equipped to automatically handle your server-side validation messages... that is not its intended purpose.  Please see `remote` method.

Comment: @Sparky

following the pattern from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999961/how-to-use-jquery-validation-plugin-with-form-level-server-side-validation

>> When I attempt to use the *showErrors* method after returning an error code from the server, I still see the same behavior where the error label won't clear on keyUp, even through JQuery Validate generated the actual error. However, If I call validate on the input or press submit, it'll be marked as valid and the error label will be hidden.

Comment: `showErrors` is for showing all errors at once... like when you want to make a list of errors.  It has nothing to do with the default showing of a single error next to a field.  It's a whole different process, which is why you don't see keyup working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Title: jQuery Validate won't clear server-inserted error messages on KeyUp

It's not designed to do that because it's a *client*-side script.

The jQuery Validate plugin generates and toggles its own validation error messages on the client via JavaScript.  Since you're blocked from submitting the form to the server until jQuery Validate is satisfied, you are not going to see any server generated validation messages in the first place.

When used with client-side validation, the server-side validation messages would never be seen under normal conditions... server-side validation would only there to protect you in case JavaScript is disabled, broken, or bypassed.

---

**EDIT**:

If you're trying to evaluate whether an email address, user account, or whatever is already in your system, then you would use the plugin's built-in `remote` method.  This rule will use `ajax()` to call a server-side script and if your server-side script returns `true`, the rule passes validation.  If your script returns `false` or a JSON encoded string, then the rule fails validation.  If you use `false`, the default error message is used.  If you return a JSON string, like *"john smith is already in use"*, then the plugin will use the string as the error message.

See:  [jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Comment: The server-side labels are returned in the html on page load AFTER the client-side validation is satisfied and the form is submitted (ex: an email address field is properly formatted, so the form is allowed to be submitted. However, it is determined on the server that the email address already exists, and the server returns an error label)

Comment: @looselycoupled, the plugin has a method for that exact purpose called `remote`.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: yea, I saw that. One of the problems is that we want to validate things like passwords when a user is attempting to delete their account. In that case, we don't want constant password checking being done on the server on every keyup. We just want to return the error message after they submit the form.

Comment: @looselycoupled, you could conditionally disable `onkeyup` using a custom function.

Comment: heres a link to a post where someone else is following the server generated label paradigm, and it appears to work for him, with generated="true" set as a parameter:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/430

Comment: @looselycoupled, see my last comment under your OP.  `showErrors` is not the correct method.  If you want to programmatically trigger validation on a field and subsequently toggle any messages, use the `.valid()` method attached to that field.  You would also need to create a custom event handler for keyup.

Comment: @looselycoupled, can you try to simulate this issue within a jsFiddle?

Comment: Decided to use the remote validation method where possible, and a slight hack with the server-generated error labels when not possible. For the latter, I'm essentially calling valid() on the focus event on the input field with the server generated error label. The field gets marked as valid and error label is hidden, allowing the form to resubmit (assuming the client-side validation passes as well).

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked, when I customized error message displayed after getting markup from server.

Note: erroneous fields have data-error-messages attribute, with error messages, splitted by ";":

```
this.showErrorMessages = function($root) {
    var handlerInstance = this;
    var validator = $(handlerInstance.instance.form).validate();
    var originalErrorMap = validator.errorMap;
    var originalErrorList = validator.errorList;
    var errorMap = {};
    var errorList = [];
    $root.find('[data-error-messages]').each(function() {
        var errorMessages = $(this).attr('data-error-messages').split(';');
        var propertyName = $(this).attr('name');
        for (var i = 0; i < errorMessages.length; i++) {
            errorMap[propertyName] = errorMessages[i];
            errorList.push({ message: errorMessages[i], element: $(this).get(0) });
        }
    });
    validator.errorMap = errorMap;
    validator.errorList = errorList;
    validator.showErrors();
    validator.errorMap = originalErrorMap;
    validator.errorList = originalErrorList;
};
```

Why I had to assign errorList manually - because otherwise if i have other elements with the same name - default validation method will figure out errorList by its own, taking FIRST element with such name and highlight it.
$root contains search area, where erroneous elements are sought, so other elements outside won't be highlighted as erroneous, if having the same names.